# how to add a second application to github?

Tags: github

I successfully created my first repository (first_app) from my local machine and pushed  the copy of master to github (Account/user shown as xyz).

Now I am trying to add a second application and push it out. But I keep getting errors.  Here is the log of commands run to create the second application and the messages received:

```
~/rails_projects/dem3>sudo git remote add origin git@github.com:xyz/dem3
~/rails_projects/dem3>git push
ERROR: xyz/dem3.git doesn't exist. Did you enter it correctly?
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
~/rails_projects/dem3>
```

As you can see the "remote add" command goes through without issues.  I see the following entries in dem3/.git/config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:xyz/dem3
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Tabrez

Comment: v2p - yes you hit it on the head!  I thought that would also happen with the same command but apparently the setup has via github gui needs to be done manually.  It worked after that! If you can put that as an answer I can accept and close this question out. Thx.

Comment: Not at all :) Nice to see, that I help you to find problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you create a repository for your second application on github.com (through web-interface)?